# How to do I fully solve this monty hall type of problem?. I need different perspectives

Tags: r, simulation

This here is monty hall type of problem that I'm trying to solve where we
assume that there's $5,000 behind one gate and cows behind the other two gates. The contender selects a gate and after that is displayed with two choices.

1. Conclude the game and take $2,000.
2. Have Monty Hall pick one of the other two gates at random. If the gate picked, contains $5,000, the player will automatically lose. If the gate that is selected contains a cow, then the contender has another two options

stay with their initial choice or
change gates
Of the 3 possibilities (conclude the game and take $2,000, keep playing but stick with their initial choice, or keep playing but change gates), which strategy/strategies) will produce/produces the highest expected value for winnings?. I'm trying to simulate 5000 plays of this game

Below is code for only part of the problem.

```
set.seed(123555)
monty <- function(switch=F) {
  gates = sample(c('money', 'cow', 'cow'), 3)
  pick = sample(1:3, 1)
  
  if (switch) {
    # if you switch after Monty showed you a cow behind the other two gates,
    # you win if $5000 is not behind chosen gate
    gates[pick] != 'money'
  } else {
    gates[pick] == 'money'
  }
}
```

the function above doesn't return anything

But below I did something much simpler

```
no_switch = sapply(1:5000, FUN=function(i) monty())
switch = sapply(1:5000, FUN=function(i) monty(switch=T))

c(mean(no_switch), mean(switch))
```

```
[1] 0.3366 0.6594
```

But I'm not sure if this is how to sole this problem

Comment: This is not how to do this. I don't understand how `switch` and `no_switch` contain approximately the right values, or indeed any values as your function does not seem to return anything. Have a read of [this](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/functions.html#return-values).

Comment: Hi, If you copy the function exactly then it returns [1] 0.3366 0.6594

Comment: There is a common misconception in rules.  What is not realized is Monty Hall has prior knowledge of which door has the prize, so he always chooses the door with the "cow", thus the prize is always available for the contestant to stay or switch.

Comment: but how do I write a function explaining that  initially there is 2 choices, then if number 2 is picked , then it is either automatic loss due to $5000 behind the gate or two further options. So this is like a tree which I'm struggling to write

Comment: It's hard to judge without the context of the calling function. You need to have both a `player_pick` and a `monty_pick`, and maybe something like `monty_pick = sample(setdiff(1:3, player_pick), size = 1)` to make sure Monty's pick is different than the player's fit.